# How to call async function over an array of elements synchronously?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

How to call async function over an array of elements synchronously in such a way that the next async function should be called only after the completion of async call over the current element.

for instance if we look at the following piece of code.

```
const fetch = require("cross-fetch");

function wait(a) {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${a}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json));
}
const data = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

async function test() {
    for (const ele of data) {
        await wait(ele);
    }
}

test();
```

whenever I am executing the above piece of code it is logging responses randomly but not synchronously according to the array. i.e

```
{"userId":1,"id":8,"title":"quo adipisci enim quam ut ab","completed":true}
{"userId":1,"id":9,"title":"molestiae perspiciatis ipsa","completed":false}
{"userId":1,"id":10,"title":"illo est ratione doloremque quia maiores aut","completed":true}
{"userId":1,"id":7,"title":"illo expedita consequatur quia in","completed":false}
{"userId":1,"id":1,"title":"delectus aut autem","completed":false}
{"userId":1,"id":6,"title":"qui ullam ratione quibusdam voluptatem quia omnis","completed":false}
{"userId":1,"id":3,"title":"fugiat veniam minus","completed":false}
{"userId":1,"id":5,"title":"laboriosam mollitia et enim quasi adipisci quia provident illum","completed":false}
{"userId":1,"id":2,"title":"quis ut nam facilis et officia qui","completed":false}
```

Here you can clearly see that the responses are not in order. Is there any way that these function can be called synchronously but only after completing the current call.

Comment: [`for await .. of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of)

Comment: still confused with it? can you tell how it works @HereticMonkey

Comment: Just go with the answer you've got from spender.

Answer (score 3):

You function `wait` is not returning its `Promise`, so you're actually awating `undefined` (I'm surprised this doesn't blow-up). Therefore asynchrony is happening in a fire-and-forget fashion. All promises are started in the same execution frame (rather than in consecutive order when the previous promise completes).

Add a `return` statement here:

```
function wait(a) {
  return fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${a}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));
}
```

By returning the `Promise`, the `await` in your loop will now block (asynchronously) until the returned `Promise` completes. The rest of your code now operates as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
function wait(a) {
    return fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${a}`)
        .then(response => response.json());
}
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

async function test() {
    for await (const ele of data) {
        await wait(ele).then(json => console.log(JSON.stringify(json)));
    }
}
```

Hopefully, This will work .

Answer (score 0):

From MDN, [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) expression...

> causes async function execution to pause until a Promise is settled (that is, fulfilled or rejected), and to resume execution of the async function after fulfillment. When resumed, the value of the await expression is that of the fulfilled Promise.

However, in your function, the function is returning <del>`null`</del> `undefined`, and also from the docs,

> If the value of the expression following the await operator is not a Promise, it's converted to a resolved Promise.

```
async function test() {
    for (const ele of data) {
        // returned value from wait(el) is not a promise, it's null
        await wait(ele);
    }
}
```

Adding a `return` should fix it!

```
function wait(a) {
    // missing return statement 
    // to fix, add a `return` infront of fetch
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${a}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json));
}
```

Comment: `null` and `undefined` are different things in JS. A `void` function "returns" `undefined`, *not* `null`.

Answer (score -1):

Just wrap the function's code inside of a Promise, like this:

```
function wait(a) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${a}`)
      .then(response => resolve(response.json()))
      .then(json => reject(json));
    });  
}
```

Then the rest of the code should work as expected.